# Get the real name of an exported class in Webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6

Forgive me if this question title is wrong or misleading. This is hard to explain and I'm very new to webpack.

**Problem**

I have a class with a render method that returns a template literal of HTML.

```
var Foo = new class {
    _click() {
        alert("great");
    }
    render() {
        return `<button onclick="Foo._click()">Test</button>`;
    }
  }();

 document.getElementById("root").innerHTML = Foo.render();
```

`Foo._click` gets fired fine - **except** if I export this class in webpack.

Since its no longer a global variable on window[] how do I access it? addEventListener is not an option.

Comment: `onclick="Foo._click()"` That looks a lot like JSX (usually used with React). You might want to look into JSX (and a framework to go with it).

Comment: You need to export it to the global scope using `exports-loader` with any arbitrary name, then use that name

Comment: It is ES6 template literals.

Comment: I don't want to shim it as a global (I think thats what export loader does), but is there another way I can reference it in the template literal? Again, new to webpack.

Comment: @EricHarms you cannot reference it - that variable is not global anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this very file you need to use [`exports-loader`](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/exports-loader).

Its use would look similar to

```
exports-loader?window.Foo!path/to/file.js
```

then the `Foo` would be available globally.

Comment: Is there a way to not make it global and reference it. The reason is I have a lot of classes like this. Secondly, how does this work with ES6. I went to the exports-loader page and it looks like its favoring require?

Comment: @EricHarms `onclick` implies the code is evaluated in the global scope

Comment: @EricHarms Which is why no-one these days uses string-based templates or `onclick` anymore if they can avoid it :)

Comment: Now I am getting undefined. import {Foo} from "exports-loader?window.Foo!./Foo";

Comment: You get `undefined` for what? If you export it as `window.Foo` - it's available as `window.Foo`.